# Xcode 8 coreData и NSManagedObjectSubclass

Tags: objective-c, xcode, coredata

В новом xCode (8) пропала из меню file -> new file -> NSManagedObjectSubclass. 
  Я хочу из entity coreDatы создать класс, что бы можно было работать со связями и проперти. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: посмотрите Xcode automatic subclass generation https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/WhatNewCoreData2016/ReleaseNotes.html

Comment: Выбираете модель - Editor - Create NSManagedObject Subclass и XCode сам вам их сгенерирует

Answer (score -1):

Заходишь в проекте, в файл кор даты, сверху жмёшь `Editor->Create NSManagedObjectSubclass`